# convert classes from asp.net 4 to asp.net 3.5 (Massive Lib)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, dynamic-data

I have been using massive [Massive Lib (github)](https://github.com/robconery/massive)

for asp.net 4 project.

I have now inherited a project from a previous developer, which is in asp.net 3.5.

Most of 'massive' I can still use but there are 2 classes which due to asp.net 4 features can not be used. My plan is to create 2 new classes, with the same names to patch the same functionality.

The two classes are 'DynamicObject' and 'ExpandoObject'

I need to some how create two classes, to patch the asp.net 4 functionality.

The only issue is I have no Idea how to go about it
(I have hit google hard, and have got nothing more than an idea that Dictionary's need to be used)

Any one any ideas or can point me in the right direction?

(the two classes are asp.net built in)

Thanks

EDIT:

Im aware than 4.0 can't run on 3.5, and that 4.0 is just 'better' however upgrading is out of my hands, Im aware that massive uses 4.0, However the classes I want to mimic are not part of massive, but of the 4.0 framework.

I was hoping there was a way to recreate those two classes and somehow mimic there functionality, but I guess not

Comment: I've quicky check the Massive code source, as it is open source, and unfortunately it's strongly based on the .NET 4 dynamic feature, so you'll not be able to convert it to .NET 3.5 without rewrite almost all the library.

Comment: Since you have no idea how to create these two classes yourself.  The path of least trouble would be to simply update YOUR code to support .NET 4 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  Dynamic is one of the new features supported by .Net 4 that is specifically an addition not available in 3.5

Your best bet is to host the app in a 4.0 environment so you can make use of the DLLs.

Comment: +1. Moving to 4.0 may be easier (and likely beneficial in general) than trying to re-implement dynamic objects in 2.0 (which also could be throw-away effort as eventually you probably move to 4.0 anyway).

Comment: Even more than trying to recreate it, 3.5 just doesn't support dynamic syntax.  Even if you could muddle through the functionality, the syntax would block you.  Not to mention that the .net 4 library won't even run on 3.5 for lack of dependancies.